# Zend Framework: How to call a custom function created in bootstrap?

Tags: zend-framework, bootstrapping

I am using Zend Framework v 1.10

I have created a custom function in the bootstrap file:

```
<?php

class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{

    public function init(){   }

    public function helloworld(){ echo 'hello';}
}
?>
```

How do I call the helloworld() function from an Action within the Index Controller?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone can call a function in the bootstrap class without making any object of the class. Bootstrap automatically calls custom functions which have the `_init` keyword as a prefix. Such as:

```
public function _initIndia() { 
     echo 'Proud to be an Indian'; 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$this->getFrontController()->getParam('bootstrap')->helloworld();
```

should work. But I can't think of any reason why you would want to do this - the bootstrap is for initialising application resources, its job is done long before controllers get involved. Perhaps whatever you are doing in the method should be a resource or in a controller plugin?

Comment: Then what is the difference between the bootstrap file and the index.php file that sits under the public folder which I found under the Quickstart code sample on the zend official site?

Comment: Both are part of the initialisation process. The index.php calls the bootstrap class.

Comment: I agree with Tim. The index.php is implementing the Front Controller pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) in that it's the central point that handles all requests and looks after the dependent processes for the application to operate effectively - such as bootstrapping.

The bootstrap however is more specific in that it takes care of the initialisation of resources for the application, such as routing, caching, navigation and pagination; amongst other things.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're wanting to achieve here, but have you considered the preDispatch and postDispatch methods (http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.action.html#zend.controller.action.prepostdispatch) in controllers?

Answer (score -1):

Any public functions you create in the bootstrap that begin with `_init` will automatically be called by the bootstrapping code.  For instance:

```
public function _initHelloWorld() { echo 'hello'; }
```

Comment: The question asked about a function called helloworld, not _initHelloWorld so the OP seems to know that this is the case.

Comment: And by the way, it does not need to be public to be called Automatically. Protected Methods do get called Automatically